# Как найти менеджеров, у которых в подчинении не менее 7 сотрудников

Tags: sql, oracle-study

Задание такое:
По данным из таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES сформировать список тех менеджеров, у которых в подчинении находится не менее 7 сотрудников.
Я попробовала сделать так:

```
select count(manager_id) as count_worker from HR.EMPLOYEES 
group by manager_id 
having count(manager_id) > 6
```

Но выводит не верный результат, и хотелось бы чтобы выводил еще employee_id для идентификации менеджера

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо запрос изменить таким образом, что бы выводился ID менеджера и количество работников

```
select manager_id, count(*) as count_worker 
from HR.EMPLOYEES 
group by manager_id  
having count(*) > 6;
```

Если количество работников не нужно в наборе полей, то запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
select manager_id
from HR.EMPLOYEES 
group by manager_id  
having count(*) > 6;
```

Comment: Задача не требует вывода количества. Нужен чисто список манагеров.

Comment: Вы правы, можете подсказать, как реализовать?

Comment: @AlicaSmith Обновил ответ, добавил селект без вывода количества работников