# Поиск дубликатов по строкам pl sql

Tags: sql, plsql

Как найти полностью идентичные строки?
И как найти идентичные строки, в которых одинаково все, кроме одного столбца?
Например, на скриншоте последние две строки имеют одинаковое всё кроме первого столбца.
А так же, есть вторая и четвертая ПОЛНОСТЬЮ одинаковые строки.
Как их вывести на экран отдельно в виде дубликатов? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сгруппируйте по нужным вам полям, посчитайте количество и потом выберите записи, количество которых больше 1. Вот тут пример такого запроса -> [Как вывести записи, количество которых больше заданного значения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1469493/1469504#1469504)

Comment: Благодарю. Все работает.