# Как вывести данные менеджеров, у которых более 5 подчиненных, используя подзапрос?

Tags: sql

Есть такая задача:

Используя таблицу HR.EMPLOYEES, отобразить данные о сотрудниках (имя и фамилия, оклад, идентификатор департамента, номер телефона и e-mail), каждый из которых является менеджером для более 5 подчиненных.

Попробовал реализовать вот так, но выходит ошибка:

```
select first_name, last_name, department_id, phone_number, email from hr.employees
where (select manager_id from hr.employees 
        where count(manager_id) > 5)
```

База данных выглядит вот так:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90
```

Comment: Возможно это - [вывод менеджеров с количеством подчиненных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1469493/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-sql/1469504#1469504)  поможет вам в решении вашего вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводим список сотрудников, у которых в подчинении более 5 сотрудников:

Вложенным запросом получаем ID сотрудников, у которых более 5 подчиненных и по этим ID фильтруем.

```
select 
    emp.first_name
  , emp.last_name
  , emp.department_id
  , emp.phone_number
  , emp.email 
from hr.employees emp
where emp.EMPLOYEE_ID in (
    select manager_id
    from HR.EMPLOYEES 
    group by manager_id  
    having count(*) > 5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное как-то так

```
select first_name, last_name, department_id, phone_number, email from hr.employees
where employee_id IN (
select manager_id from (select manager_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt from hr.employees) AS t 
where t.cnt > 5)
```

Т.е. сначала мы считаем количество подчиненных для каждого менеджера, а потом выбираем идентификаторы менеджеров у которых подчиненных больше пяти. А уже потом полученные идентиифкаторы вставляем в условие для выборки сотрудников.